# Is there a way to use setOnClickListener with an Android Spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

The java.lang.RuntimeException is "Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead," but that is not correct. I am using setOnItemClickListener to do some stuff based on the new selection, but I also need to do some stuff before the user changes the selection. Specifically, I am collecting data for each selection that needs to be saved to a file before moving to another selection, since the other selection is associated with different set of data. Is there a way to use setOnClickListener with an Android Spinner?

```
spinner.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do some stuff before the user changes the selection
        ...

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
            // Do some stuff based onItemSelected
            ...
```

Comment: A new (working) solution is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520801/406090

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to set the Click listener on the underlying view (normally a TextView with id: android.R.id.text1) of the spinner. To do so:

- Create a custom Spinner
- In the constructor (with attributes) create the spinner by supplying the layout android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
- Do a findViewById(android.R.id.text1) to get the TextView
- Now set the onClickListener to the TextView

Comment: so the onclicklistener would be defined inside the custom spinner? SHould I also define an onclicklistener on the spinner itself in the activity?

Comment: I tried the approach suggested by you-the click is registered but the dropdown still works. How do I prevent the dropdown from working since on click on the spinner I am going to another screen.

Comment: I did that with android:clickable="false"

Answer (score 9):

You can replicate the an onclick event using ontouch events

```
    this.spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    this.spinner.setClickable(false);
    this.spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.v(TAG, "spinner touch");

            //replicating a click
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                v.playSoundEffect(android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: why did you call spinner.setClickable(false) ?

Comment: i dont understand either.