# How to capture talkback onClick on a Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, accessibility

The normal way of capturing an onClick event on a spinner ([How to capture onClick event in Android for a spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213015/how-to-capture-onclick-event-in-android-for-a-spinner)) doesn't trigger the event for a talkback user. Neither the onKeyListener or the onTouchListener is triggered. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Whats a talkback user?

Comment: @psypher talkback is the built in screen reader on android for visually impaired users, similar to voiceover on ios, that's why the `accessibility` tag is on this question

Answer (score 0):

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This would be for `onItemSelected`, not an `onClick` on the spinner itself

Answer (score 0):

```
spinnerFundTransferSelectTo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
TextView selectedText = (TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0);
String text = mAccountsTo.get(position).getactType();
String talkBackText = " account number ending with " + mAccountsTo.get(position).getactType(); // mAccountsTo.get(position).getactType() is one value from array list
selectedText.setContentDescription(talkBackText);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

}
}
```

get the view of the `textview` and assign to selectedText. After that `setContentDescription` for that view

Comment: Code only answers aren't much use to anyone without some explanation along with it.