# Android - how to invoke onNavigationItemSelected when spinner item is re-selected

Tags: android, android-actionbar, spinner

I am using the spinner in the action bar for navigation. The problem is, the ***onNavigationItemSelected*** is not called when the selected item is the same as the previously selected one.
I have looked at similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854329/spinner-onitemselected-not-called-when-selected-item-remains-the-same/11227847#11227847) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183562/android-spinner-item-on-click-doest-work-if-it-is-already-selected)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863378/how-to-hide-one-item-in-an-android-spinner)
but none of them provide working solution, specific to the required drop down navigation within action bar.

I am using the following code:

```
public class TestSpinner extends Activity implements
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {  

private Integer mPosition;       

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();  
    final String[] EventTypes = getResources().getStringArray(    
            R.array.spinner_items);

    mPosition = -1;

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(                
            actionBar.getThemedContext(),  
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, android.R.id.text1,               
            EventTypes);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

....

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {

    if (mPosition > -1) {               
        mPosition = position;
            // execute required code on spinner item selection  

        return true;

    } else {
        mPosition = 0;
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Note, that I use the mPosition flag to prevent the onNavigationItemSelected to execute the code when the Action Bar is first created.
I wonder if there is a more elegant, recommended way of doing that ?

However, the key question is, how to generate a callback to the onNavigationItemSelected when the same spinner item in Action Bar is re-selected ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

Comment: @Sam - my code works the same way as the actionBar example you have suggested (I have tested it). However, you have completely missed the key point of my question: the actionBar example code has exactly the same problem: it **does not** generate a callback to the onNavigationItemSelected when the same spinner item in Action Bar is re-selected. Do you have any other suggestions how to solve this problem ?