# Difference between getView & getDropDownView in SpinnerAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, baseadapter

When you implement SpinnerAdapter you get [getDropDownView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29), how does it differ from `getView` which you have when you need to extend `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If we look at the following code, we have name and value array in getView and getDropDownView.

```
private void initView() {
    SpinnerDropDownAdapter sddadapter = new SpinnerDropDownAdapter(this);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sddadapter.name);

    Spinner getViewSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.getview_sp);
    getViewSP.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner getViewWDropDownSP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.getview_w_drop_down_sp);
    getViewWDropDownSP.setAdapter(sddadapter);
}

static class SpinnerDropDownAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        SpinnerAdapter {
    Context context;

    SpinnerDropDownAdapter(Context ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }

    String[] name = { " One", " Two", " Three", " Four", " Five", " Six",
            " Seven", " Eight" };
    String[] value = { " 1", " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8" };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int pos) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name[pos];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setText(name[position]);
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text = new TextView(context);
        text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        text.setText(value[position]);
        return text;
    }
}
```

If getDropDownView method is not implemented, the drop down pop up will get the view from getView. Thus, it will only show name.

[image: getView]

When both getView and getDropDownView is implemented, the former getting *name* and the latter getting *value*, the spinner at rest will get *name* from getview and the drop down pop up will get *value*.
[image: getView and getDropDownView]

Comment: can we get view at here as like simple spinner ?

Comment: In my case at least, if getDropDownView is not implemented, I get a null View.

Answer (score 58):

The accepted answer seems a little complicated, so for simplicity

- `getView` - the value shown on the spinner before the user presses the 
  spinner, where each value view can be adjusted with the convertView parameter
- `getDropDownView` - list of values the user can select after the user presses the spinner, where each value in the list can be adapted with the convertView parameter

Comment: They are `View`s, not values. `getView()` is for the single `View` you see before the `Spinner` is tapped. `getDropDownView()` is for the vertical stack of `View`s that you see when the `Spinner` is tapped. You can use the two methods to create/populate each of the two types of `View`s as per your requirements.

Answer (score 7):

`getView` and `getDropDownView` can show different layout.

I create a Spinner and use `class ImageTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>` as an adapter.  I override `getView` so that it can show both `ImageView` and `TextView`.  However, I don't override `getDropDownView`.

This is a screenshot before the spinner is pressed

[image]

and after the spinner is pressed.

[image]

I initialize the spinner with the following code.

```
String[] spinnerTexts = {"Tanzania", "Thailand"};
int[] spinnerImages = {R.drawable.tanzania, R.drawable.thailand};

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ImageTextAdapter(this, spinnerTexts, spinnerImages);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is ImageTextAdapter.java

```
public class ImageTextAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    int[] images;

    public ImageTextAdapter(Context ctx, String[] texts, int[] images) {
        super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, texts);
        this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(getItem(position));

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can use SpinnerAdapter as this:

```
public class FolderSpinnerAdpater extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

In BaseAdapter.java

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Override `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`，return different view,you will find the difference.

[image]