# Same code on getView and getDropDownView on ANDROID spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433874/difference-between-getview-getdropdownview-in-spinneradapter) question, making me understand why I must override `getDropDownView` and `getView` within my `SpinnerAdapter` class:

```
SpinnerActionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements SpinnerAdapter
```

The problem is I have the exact same code both in the `getDropDownView` and `getView`, which I do not think is a very beautiful solution.

Does everyone who uses `SpinnerAdapter` have this code duplicated as well?  Does anyone have a better solution?

Note:  My code is working perfectly so there is no need to post it; it just looks strange because I have a lot of duplicated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call getView from your getDropDownView and return result

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getView(position, convertView, parent);
}
```

Comment: So sorry, i forgot to accept your answer. Thanks a lot