# How to enable / disable drop down list of Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, dropdown

I created a spinner and its working fine.

All I want is that when i click on spinner it show `drop down` that's it. I want `un-clickble` drop down list.

Using this

```
    viewHolder.like.setEnabled(false);
    viewHolder.like.setClickable(false);
```

my spinner set `unclickble`.

If anyone need more detail about spinner I can post more details. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to override **isEnabled** and disable that position by **return false** else **return true**.
You can override the same method where you have override **getDropDownView** method

Comment: thnkx  I will try. Can u tell me how to show fix name always for drop down

Comment: just use the **spinner.setSelection(0);** to by default select the value at zero position. which in most cases will be the hint value.

Comment: Did you find it helpful. Please do not forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: I want to display always first value even after selection of other value

Comment: in **onItemSelected** method hold the selected position into an variable. and reselect the selection to zero position as already told. Hope it works. Upvote  the answer.

Comment: ok got it....thnkx again. And one more thing Can i change text color of only first value ?

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433874/difference-between-getview-getdropdownview-in-spinneradapter)