# Spinner with custom array adapter

Tags: android, class, spinner, android-arrayadapter, custom-arrayadapter

I am trying to populate a spinner from a custom array adapter. Everything works perfectly except when you click on the spinner to choose a new value it displays a long line of code for each item. However, after clicking on the long line of code displays the correct name and gives the correct value though.

Example of what it does

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhUqw.png

Custom array adapter

```
private void populateCompanyList()
    {
        ArrayAdapter<CompanyClass> Adapter = new OnlyListAdapter();
        Company.setAdapter(Adapter);
    }

    private class OnlyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CompanyClass>
    {
        public OnlyListAdapter() {
            super(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, listCompany);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            //Make sure we have a view to work with
            View itemView = convertView;
            if (itemView == null)
                itemView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);

            CompanyClass currentCompany = listCompany.get(position);

            TextView Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            Name.setText(currentCompany.getName());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), currentCompany.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            return itemView;
        }
    }
```

public class CompanyClass {

```
String ID;
String Name;

public CompanyClass(String ID, String Name)
{
    this.ID=ID;
    this.Name=Name;
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
```

}

Comment: Does your `CompanyClass` provides `toString()` override?

Comment: override `getDropDownView()` too

Comment: @IvanTodorović I included the class in my edit, thanks

Comment: @pskink Where would I need to override the getDropDownView(), can you maybe provide an example? thanks

Comment: `ArrayAdapter#getDropDownView` or as Ivan says, simply override `CompanyClass#toString()` method (returning just `Name` for example)

Comment: I found an example of what @pskink explained https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433874/difference-between-getview-getdropdownview-in-spinneradapter thanks for the help

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
  @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.Name;          
    }
```