# Issue with the Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have used Spinner to display toast on particular item selected in Spinner.

I am displaying toast when "other" is selected in Spinner.
I have done it as below :

```
spinnerTemp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerTemp);
    spinnerTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(spinnerTemp.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("other")){
                Toast.makeText(SocialLoginActivity.this, "Displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

**The issue is** When I am selecting "other" for the **first time**, toast is displaying.. : FINE. Now, on the spot If i select "other" **again**, then toast is not displaying. Why ?

Now, if i select some other value and try again selecting "other", its working fine. Issue is with the selecting "other" one after another.

What might be the issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: it means in first time selection work fine and next time not getting proper toast.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854329/spinner-onitemselected-not-called-when-selected-item-remains-the-same

Comment: you should use onItemClickListener in place of onItemSelectedListener.

Answer (score 0):

Here a little better implementation:

```
@Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // On selecting a spinner item
      String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

      // Showing selected spinner item
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
spinnerTemp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerTemp);
spinnerTemp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String item = spinnerTemp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase("other")){
            Toast.makeText(SocialLoginActivity.this, "Displayed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
});
```