# How to maintain the state of a Spinner selection?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have spinners in my fragment. Selecting each option of my spinners gives me different scores fetching from database. Now, I don't want to fetch the data from database if I select the same option from spinner consecutively. In my current code it is fetching the data on each selection. Is there any way that I can maintain the previous selection of spinners, so that I can give a check to database hit. Thanks.

Comment: Can u post what you have tried till now ?

Comment: Added my answer for the above problem.

Comment: This is not a way to ask question in stackoverflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spinner : onItemSelected not called when selected item remains the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854329/spinner-onitemselected-not-called-when-selected-item-remains-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the above problem and was able to find a good solution. I created a custom spinner taking a reference from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227847/2734855

The overridden method `setSelection(int position)` of Spinner class actually gives the event hit back to the `OnItemSelectedListener` which helps to track the previous spinner selection.