# Show a toast message when an android spinner is empty

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner which is populated from the database. So if the spinner is clicked with no items in it,a spinner with an empty list item is shown.I want to avoid showing the spinner when it is empty and show a toast message. I have the logic to check the count of the items and show the toast message, but I cannot find out where to call the function.What is the event   called when clicking the spinner and loading the spinner items?

Comment: I added some code, for me it works entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spinner` is a subclass of `View`, so, `View.setOnClickListener()` can be used to change `onClick()` implementation which will be called when it is clicked. You can override `onClick()` to check if the `Spinner` is empty and then show the `Toast`.

**Correction:**

Since you cannot `setOnClickListener` for `Spinner`, you can use the solution suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928071/android-setting-a-spinner-onclicklistener/8520801#8520801) (the contents of which I've pasted below).

Instead of setting the spinner's OnClickListener, we are setting OnTouchListener and OnKeyListener.

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(Spinner_OnTouch);
spinner.setOnKeyListener(Spinner_OnKey);
```

and the listeners:

```
private View.OnTouchListener Spinner_OnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            doWhatYouWantHere();
        }
        return true;
    }
};
private static View.OnKeyListener Spinner_OnKey = new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
            doWhatYouWantHere();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The error message shown is 'Don't call setOnClickListener on AdapterView.You probably may want to use setOnItemClickListener.'.But this is not suitable for my purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Why not set an `onClickListener`?

```
Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
s.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        checkForItemCount();    //where you show your Toast if it's empty.
    }
});
```

**Edit:**
I think I do not completely cover your question, so I tried some code myself. This works entirely for you.

```
final Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); // get reference
    ArrayList<String> mList = new ArrayList<String>();  //some list without items
    s.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mList));
    s.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && mList.size() == 0) {
                toast("Empty"); //lazy method for toasting
                s.setPressed(false); //closes the spinner.
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried this,but the error message shows that you cannot set onclicklistener for the spinner

Comment: Try using `s.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {` instead

Comment: This works but the toast message is shown 3-4 times...Is touchlistener called whenever setselection is called?

Comment: @viks In that case, just use the setOnClickListerer(). The touchListener might not be a good idea.

Comment: checking if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) in ontouchlistener  works for me

Comment: @viks Great idea, I put it in the code. If you ever want to open your spinner (when the spinner if filled, for example, call `s.performClick()`).

Answer (score 0):

This is the function when an item is selected if that's what you were asking. For more help you will need to post your code. Otherwise, we have no idea what you have going on

`spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()`

Comment: No,I want to avoid showing the spinner items if the count is 0. I have to check when the user clicks on the textbox like view shown in the place of spinner