# Android on activity result always return 0 and null intent

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I tried almost all solutions found from the net and still can't solve my problem. Would anyone please help with the following codes? I really can't make it work. Even if I tried to put the setresult code in onBackPressed event, the parent activity still get result code = 0.

1. Start activity for result in the parent [CreatePostActivity] on touch event of a spinner:

@Override

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        appState = ((ApplicationProvider) getApplicationContext());

    LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mContent = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_create_post, null);
    setContentView(mContent);

    spinnerCategory = (Spinner) mContent.findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);
    spinnerCategory.setOnTouchListener(this);

    arrayCategory = new String[] { getResources().getString(R.string.create_post_category) };
    adapterCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayCategory);
    spinnerCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory);}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.spinnerCategory) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("CategoryId", categoryId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePostActivity_Category.class);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        // intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Variables.CREATEPOST_CATEGORY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    return true;
}
```

1. Child [CreatePostActivity_Category] contains a listview and initialize with adapter like below:

listitem_select_checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewItem"
        style="@style/Heading.h2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CreatePostActivity to receive :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Variables.CREATEPOST_CATEGORY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else
            System.out.println("CANCEL");
    }
}
```

CreatePostActivity_Category:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CategoryAdapter(CategoryModel[] list) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_select_checkbox, null);

        TextView textViewItem = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
        textViewItem.setText(mListItems[position].getDescription((String) appState.getPreference(Variables.PREF_LANG)));

        CheckBox checkBoxItem = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxItem);
        if (categoryId == mListItems[position].CategoryId)
            checkBoxItem.setChecked(true);
        checkBoxItem.setTag(R.id.tag_id, mListItems[position].CategoryId);
        checkBoxItem.setTag(R.id.tag_desc, mListItems[position].getDescription((String) appState.getPreference(Variables.PREF_LANG)));
        checkBoxItem.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(((CompoundButton) v).getTag(R.id.tag_id).toString());
            String desc = ((CompoundButton) v).getTag(R.id.tag_desc).toString();

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("CategoryId", id);
            bundle.putString("Category", desc);
            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);

            if (getParent() == null) {
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
            } else {
                getParent().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
            }
            finish();
        }
    }
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mContext = this;
    appState = ((ApplicationProvider) getApplicationContext());
    database = DatabaseHelper.instance();

    LayoutInflater inflate = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    mContent = inflate.inflate(R.layout.activity_create_post_category, null);
    setContentView(mContent);

    ImageButton ibtnClose = (ImageButton) mContent.findViewById(R.id.ibtnClose);
    ibtnClose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    listViewCategory = (ListView) mContent.findViewById(R.id.listViewCategory);
    Cursor cr = database.select("SELECT category_id, edesc, cdesc FROM category");
    mListItems = new CategoryModel[cr.getCount()];

    if (cr != null) {
        if (cr.moveToFirst()) {
            int i = 0;
            do {
                int categoryId = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("category_id"));
                String cdesc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("cdesc"));
                String edesc = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("edesc"));
                mListItems[i] = new CategoryModel(categoryId, cdesc, edesc);
                i++;
            } while (cr.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    cr.close();

    CategoryAdapter mCategoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(mContext, mListItems);
    listViewCategory.setAdapter(mCategoryAdapter);

    mData = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    categoryId = mData.getInt("CategoryId");
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for finish child activity? share code of CreatePostActivity_Category

Comment: it is commented inside the getview method in the adapter.

Comment: why that is commented? You should replace the whole listner from adapter into activity

Comment: Why its commented? setResult is essential.

Comment: I didn't comment it in my code, I just want to make it clear in the question.

Comment: I also tried to move the listener out but it didn't work.

Comment: There are too many things which you removed from code before put here.. it would be easy if you add your full adapter code...

Comment: just updated. put the whole adapter , please check and help.

Comment: what is `mContext`? Where did you initialised...

Comment: mContext = this; initialize in onCreate

Comment: see added answer.. and tell me if problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out!!!

The original on touch listener I wrote has been fired three times, that's why it was unable to retrieve the actual return result.

Solved it by this --> [Setting a spinner onClickListener() in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928071/android-setting-a-spinner-onclicklistener)

```
private View.OnTouchListener Spinner_OnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            if (v.getId() == R.id.spinnerCategory) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("CategoryId", categoryId);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, CreatePostActivity_Category.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Variables.CREATEPOST_CATEGORY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Everything works.
Thanks all for the suggested and correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

Before call the finish() method in your child activity,add the below code:

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

Fllowing is new:
1、Add new variable:

```
Context mContext;
```

2、Change your adapter constructor:

```
public CategoryAdapter(Context context,CategoryModel[] list) {
    mContext = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

3、Change finish() in adapter to:

```
((Activity)mContext).finish();
```

4、Replace your adapter's definition in your parent activity with the construction mentioned in Step 2

Comment: try step 1、2、3、4 @WinnieL