# Spinner onClickListener doesn't get called

Tags: android, button, spinner, onclicklistener

I got a button which opens up a spinner:

```
    butonLista.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 

        {
            public void onClick(View v){

                spinnerLista.performClick();
            }  
        });
```

This is the spinner:

```
   spinnerLista = new Spinner(this);
               public void spinnerLista(){
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, masini);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinnerLista.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinnerLista.setOnItemSelectedListener(new listaOnClickListener());
   }
```

In the listaOnClickListener i have a log:

```
        public class listaOnClickListener implements OnItemSelectedListener{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long arg3) {     

        String nrInmat = String.valueOf(spinnerLista.getItemAtPosition(pos));
        Log.w("Numar inmatriculare:", nrInmat+"");
        txtNrInmat.setText(nrInmat);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
```

After i click the button, the spinner list pops up, When i click an item from the list the log doesnt appear, the commands i put in the OnClickListener arent called, what can i do?

I finally want to set an EditText to spinnerLista.getItemAtPosition(pos);

Comment: `spinnerLista()` is a function or view?

Answer (score 0):

```
   spinnerLista.performClick();
```

will perform click on the Spinner, not on the spinner individual item view.

use

```
    spinner.getOnItemClickListener().onItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
```

to perform click on individual item view.

Comment: yes, spinnerLista.performCLick(); will perform a click on the spinner, after that i'll click an individual item from the spinner. so shouldnt the onclicklistener get called?

Comment: did you mean onItemSelectedListener is not get called when you click on Spinner item?

Comment: yes, public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long arg3)

Comment: this method will not be called when you select a item which is selected previously.

Comment: where did i previously selected it?

Comment: when you set Adapter to Spinner, by default it will select first item from Adapter and will call OnItemSelectedListener. Now when you click on Spinner, It will open list of items shown as ListView and if you select first item from that list, it will not call OnItemSelectedListener as it is selected previously.

Comment: so when i set adapter to spinner, why dont i get a log or something? i dont have an actual spinner(spinnerLista = new Spinner(this);), just a button and an edittext.

Comment: do you mean spinner is not a part of your Activity Window?

Comment: no its not, i only have a button and an edittext, i press button the spinner list apears on screen, i press an item from list,the edittext gets the content of item from the selected position. Have you understood? But the onselecteditem doesnt get called when i push the item so i dont know what to put in the edittext. its that simple. sorry about my english if that was the problem.

Comment: you have created spinner dynamically but you have not added that to Activity layout

Comment: i solved it by adding a spinner with 50dp width, istead of the button, so it look the same as a button but its a spinner :) ty for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for selected item from the spinner

```
String nrInmat = String.valueOf(spinnerLista.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

Or you may have to Implement  OnItemSelectedListener in your Activity.

```
   {     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, masini);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerLista.setAdapter(adapter);           
        spinnerLista.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
@Override

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3){     

    //Do what ever you want when you click on spinner       

}

 @Override

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
```

Comment: spinnerLista.getSelectedItemPosition() returns the position.

Comment: i already have onitemselected and onnothingselected but in another function, so thoes dont get called

Comment: @Victor Hope you have implemented it,try this link..http://stackoverflow.com/a/3928324/2534313

Comment: nevermind, i'll wait for other answers, this is not what i need. i dont get any errors, its like the spinner isnt even there

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, something is probably wrong in your onItemSelectedListener subclass.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       Log.i("SPINNER-TRACE", "onItemSelected");
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
       Log.i("SPINNER-TRACE", "onNothingSelected");
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried, it doest work, the problem is onitemselectedlistener doesnt get called.

Answer (score 0):

To popup spinner on button click use spinner.performClick inside onclick event of button.

and have a look at below code to implement onItemSelectedListener for spinner.

```
    Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.colors, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(adapter);
    s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    showToast("Spinner1: position=" + position + " id=" + id);
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    showToast("Spinner1: unselected");
                }
            });
```

Also spinner.getSelectedItem() will give item which is currently selected.

You can ask if you have any further queries!

Comment: it doesnt work, the onitemselectedlistener doesnt get called, i posted all my code, sorry if it was incomplete.

Comment: Go through this tutorial and import this project in your eclipse and check weather it is running or not?  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-spinner-dropdown-example/

Comment: i already got spinners in my app that work, i know how to make a spinner. This is what i want to be an editable spinner, edittext+button.

Comment: please share your your xml and java file