# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner

Tags: java, android

I am following chapter 2 of 'Head First, Android Development' to create a Beer Advisor app, and encountered the `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner` error when running my app.

I researched past StackOverFlow questions on how to resolve the issue but did not manage to resolve the issue.

activity_find_beer.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".FindBeerActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/colour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:entries="@array/beer_colours"
        android:onClick="onClickFindBeer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/colour"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/colour"
        android:text="@string/find_beer" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/brands"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/find_beer"
        android:layout_below="@id/find_beer"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/brands" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

FindBeerActivity.java

```
package com.example.beeradvisor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FindBeerActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
    }


    public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {
        TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
        Spinner colour = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.colour);

        String selectedBeer = String.valueOf(colour.getSelectedItem());
        brands.setText(selectedBeer);
    }
}
```

Here is the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.beeradvisor, PID: 4029
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.beeradvisor/com.example.beeradvisor.FindBeerActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.widget.Spinner
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at com.example.beeradvisor.FindBeerActivity.onCreate(FindBeerActivity.java:17)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
        at com.example.beeradvisor.FindBeerActivity.onCreate(FindBeerActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
        at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:783)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3994)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:243)
        at android.widget.AbsSpinner.<init>(AbsSpinner.java:72)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:189)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:144)
        at android.widget.Spinner.<init>(Spinner.java:129)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145) 
        at com.example.beeradvisor.FindBeerActivity.onCreate(FindBeerActivity.java:17) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
Process 4029 terminated.
```

I would appreciate any advice. Thank you for reading.

Comment: I'm not sure but can you try using ```android.widget.Spinner``` instead of ```Spinner``` in your tag in xml file.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I still encountered the same error after applying your suggestion

Comment: Okay. Can you remove ```onClick``` from ```Spinner```.

Comment: There is an error related to it in stacktrace,   
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: And check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928071/setting-a-spinner-onclicklistener-in-android)

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the links you've provided. It turns out that I put the line ```android:onClick:onClickFindBeer``` in the Spinner tag instead of the Button tag.