# Perform an action on spinner opening

Tags: android, spinner

My problem is the following : at the moment I have a spinner called "projects" that I am populating in my code, but for some reasons I need to add it a title so I just do it using my adapter :

```
adapter.add("Choose a project");
```

Now I would like to remove it (via adapter.remove, this is not a problem) when the spinner in my activity is clicked (when it's opening), but the only method i am able to find is onItemSelected, which is not what I'm looking for.

Is there such thing as a `onOpenListener` or `onClickListener` for Spinner to actually execute some code when the spinner is opened, and not only when an item is selected ??

Thank you

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your listener code as well.

Comment: He doesn't have a listener. Does the spinner support an onOpenListener or onClickListener is his question.

Comment: See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523078/is-there-a-way-to-use-setonclicklistener-with-an-android-spinner

Comment: A new (working) solution is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8520801/406090

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are trying to call it inside the listener which is *probably* an anonymous class. Assuming your activity's class name is `MyActivity` use `MyActivity.this.someactivitymethod` where `someactivitymethod` is the method that you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner inherits from AbsSpinner which in turn inherits from AdapterView, which means it inherits the setOnClickListener method from AdapterView and this can be used to perform an action on clicking the spinner.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

EDIT: While this is true, it throws a runtime exception. Sorry.